# Why is my java method called twice?

Tags: java

this is the code called twice:

```
    public static DefaultListModel getFriends(int nameOrUser) {
    try {
        Friend[] allFriends = Skype.getContactList().getAllFriends();

        System.out.println("Skype contact list lenght: " + allFriends.length);

        for (Friend friend : allFriends) {
            String fullName = friend.getFullName();
            String userName = friend.toString();
            if (fullName.isEmpty()) {
                fullName = friend.getId();
            }
            fullListModel.addElement(fullName);
            userListModel.addElement(userName);
        }
    } catch (SkypeException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    if (nameOrUser == 0) {
        return fullListModel;
    } else if (nameOrUser == 1) {
        return userListModel;
    } else {
        System.out.println("You must specify a valid data type.");
    }

    return null;
}
```

The problem is that when I assign that to a jList, the jList contains the contact list twice :/

Hope I explained it well and sorry if my english was bad.

EDIT:

Here's the calling code:

```
fullList.setModel(Utils.getFriends(0));
```

Comment: The code being called is much less important in understanding why it's called multiple times than the code doing the calling

Comment: Please post your calling code.

Comment: Do you call it a secondtime in a log statement?

Comment: Why do you think its called twice? Where its called from?

Comment: I posted the calling code. I looked for another line calling that and didn't find anything.

I called it in the netbeans properties for the jList.

Comment: How do you know the code is called twice? Did you add a debug statement to the method? Or maybe the problem is that the `getAllFriends()` method adds the friends to the list twice. We can't debug your code for you.

Comment: I know it cause I can read "Skype contact list lenght: " + allFriends.length twice in the console. Anyways I solved it. just cleared the ListModel before adding the contacts :)

Answer (score 1):

The method `getFriends()` that you wrote seems to have two contradictory ways it is intended to be used:

1. to be called whenever you need a reference to one of your `ListModel`s (that is, potentially many times, and in your specific case, probably at least 2 times)
2. to be called only once, ever

This is partly because it does two different things:

1. Populate the `ListModel`s
2. Return a reference to one of the `ListModel`s

You can solve your problem by separating these two things into different methods, for example:

```
public static void populateFriends() {
    // ... add the friends into the list model ...
}

public static DefaultListModel getFriends(int nameOrUser) {
    if (nameOrUser == 0) {
        return fullListModel;
    } else if (nameOrUser == 1) {
        return userListModel;
    } else {
        // ...
}
```

When you want to add the friends into the `ListModel`s, call `populateFriends()`. When you want to get a `ListModel` reference, call `getFriends()`.

Also, I would suggest making `populateFriends()` clear the `ListModel`s (using `.clear()`) before it adds the friends. In this way, you can call it multiple times, and each time it will *refresh* the lists, instead of *duplicating* them.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I solved it thanks to a part of your answer!

Just added: fullListModel.clear(); and userListModel.clear(); at the start of the method, before the try.

Now it works. Thanks!!